# Hide property in class depending the interface

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like have access to some properties but not all. Take a look below :

```
public interface IPerson
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    string Key { get; set; }
}

public interface IOtherPerson : IPerson
{
    string Reference { get; set; }
}

public class Person : IPerson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class OtherPerson : IOtherPerson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Reference { get; set; }
}

public class MyTestClass
{
    void Call()
    {
        //In my TestMethod when I do this :
        //TestMethod(new Person()); I'd like does not have access to Reference in the TestMethod, I mean not see in intelissense)
        //TestMethod(new OtherPerson()); I'd like have access to Reference, I mean see in intelissense)
    }

    void TestMethod(IPerson p)
    {       
    }
}
```

Do you think it's possible?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want two overloads of TestMethod: `TestMethod(IPerson)` and `TestMethod(IOtherPerson)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible since you're passing `IPerson`, which is the lowest common denominator (so to speak) of the two interfaces. 
but what you can do is test to see if the object passed is implementing the interface and act on it accordingly.

```
if (p is IOtherPerson)  
{ 
      OtherPerson op= (IOtherPerson)p; 
      //Do whatever on op 
      Op.Regerence = "Ref String"; 
}
```

Then you'd have access to the IOtherPerson properties